# Adding Google Map to Contact Info Page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, google-maps, cck

I'm trying to display a Google Map inside a drupal page. The map will only have the business location marker on it, with no need for a user to submitted their own markers.

So far I've loaded the Gmap, Location, and CCK modules. I've attempted to enable a location field for Page content types, which allows me to input an address, but this doesn't display the actual map.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. Any help?

**Edit:**

The solution I went with finally was adding the JS files to the drupal header using the php command **drupal_set_html_head()** which was found through [this link](http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/embed-google-maps-drupal-node-without-module-using-php) provided by Nikit. I could get nothing else to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for Contact page? May be simpler to embed manually? http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/

Comment: Yes it only appears on one page, and doesn't need to dynamically update. But I can't figure out how to embed a map. The javascript version required a

    <body onload="initialize()">

And Drupal won't let me do that. I would rather not use the flash solution.

Comment: Look at this: http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/embed-google-maps-drupal-node-without-module-using-php 
or use iframes: http://blogoscoped.com/files/embed-google-maps.html

Comment: -1 for generic out of context answer, anybody asking about gmap integration knows link for google map api.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a block with the [gmap blocks](http://drupal.org/project/gmap_blocks) module and then set this block to display only on the contact page.

Comment: I would like to be able to place the map in my page's content and not be restricted by drupal's black placements. Also, it seems that gmap blocks is in need of an update. Even after searching through the dev forms and applying the suggested patches, the module still couldn't produce a map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to add a map to any content manually. This tutorial shows you how to get the map "Link", which you then copy into you content.
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html

Make sure that you set the "Text Format" to Full HTML - the allows the iframe tag to be used.